# User reaction time measure

Tags: node.js

I am writing a small console program to measure the reaction time of a user after writing BLINK in the console (the user only needs to press enter). The operation has to be repeated 10 times and I want to store the results in an array.
Being new at node.js, I can't get my program to loop 10 times on the input reading.

I guess it comes from some problem with the readline.close but I didn't find any clear solution.

My code :

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var count = 10;
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    var start = Date.now();
    rl.question("*** BLINK ***", function(answer) {
        var end = Date.now();
        arr.push(end-start);
        rl.close();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do, you'll probably want to modify it to suit your needs.

```
var readline = require('readline');

var count = 10;
var arr = [];
var start = Date.now();

function displayMsg(count){
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question("*** BLINK ***", function(answer) {
        var end = Date.now();
        arr.push(end-start);
        rl.close();

        if (count > 0) {
          displayMsg(count - 1)
        } else {
          console.log(arr)
        }
    });
}

displayMsg(count)
```

Comment: I thought of a recursive approach but didn't give it a try as I didn't master the readline stuff. This one works very well, thank you !